# Using Java to remove all xml attributes from a XML file that match a attribute-name?

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to use Java to remove all xml attributes from a XML file that match a attribute-name.  I am stuck at this point.  At the bottom of this code I am able to get the attribute value of each node as I loop through but I can't figure out how to delete the attribute from the Node altogether .  Any ideas?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;


public class StripAttribute { 

  public static void main(String[] args) { 

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); 
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true); 
    org.w3c.dom.Document doc = null;
    NodeList nodes = null;
    try {
      DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
      DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder(); 
      doc = db.parse("a.xml");
      nodes = doc.getChildNodes();
    }  catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for ( int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++ ) { 
      String id = nodes.item(i).getNodeValue();
      if ( id.equals("siteKey")) {
        Element el = ((Attr) nodes.item(i)).getOwnerElement(); 
        el.removeAttribute(id);
      }
    } 

    Transformer transformer;
    StreamResult result = null;
    try {
      transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
      transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
      result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter()); 
      DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc); 
      transformer.transform(source, result); 
    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerFactoryConfigurationError e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    String xmlString = result.getWriter().toString(); 
    System.out.println(xmlString); 
  } 
}
```

Here is a sample of the XML I want to transform:

https://gist.github.com/2784907

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++ ) { 
    String id = nodes.item(i).getNodeValue();
    if ( id.equals("siteKey")) {
        //doc.removeChild(nodes.item(i));
        Element el = ((Attr) nodes.item(i)).getOwnerElement(); 
        el.removeAttribute(id);
    }
}
```

It seems that the nodes returned by the query are detached from the document so getParentNode is null. - no, they are not detached, I updated the code.

I found an [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xpathjava/index.html) that says that the nodes returned by `XPathExpression` are still attached to the document.

You're original code + the above change:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    Document doc = null;
    NodeList nodes = null;
    Set<String> ids = null;
    try {
        doc = factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new File("d:/a.xml"));

        XPathExpression expr = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().compile("//@siteKey");
        ids = new HashSet<String>();
        nodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        String id = nodes.item(i).getNodeValue();
        if (id.equals("siteKey")) {
            Element el = ((Attr) nodes.item(i)).getOwnerElement();
            el.removeAttribute(id);
        }
    }

    int dupes = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        String id = nodes.item(i).getNodeValue();
        if (ids.contains(id)) {
            System.out.format("%s is duplicate\n\n", id);
            dupes++;
        } else {
            ids.add(id);
        }
    }

    System.out.format("Total ids = %d\n Total Duplicates = %d\n", ids.size(), dupes);

    Transformer transformer;
    StreamResult result = null;
    try {
        transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        transformer.transform(source, result);
    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerFactoryConfigurationError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String xmlString = result.getWriter().toString();
    System.out.println(xmlString);

}
```

Update:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    String id = nodes.item(i).getNodeValue();
    Element el = ((Attr) nodes.item(i)).getOwnerElement();
    el.removeAttribute(id);
}
```

Comment: This version of Document (org.w3c.dom.Document) doesn't seem to have a removeAttributeByName(String) method, which is what I would need.

Comment: @djangofan sorry, I din't paid enough attention. Try to get the element and then remove the attributes.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it didn't quite work.  I updated my code in my question to reflect the changes.  I'll give you an upvote for helping me.  Or, maybe it did work and I am just printing out the wrong object?  Need to research...

Comment: @djangofan the first problem is that we compare string using == :) fixed that, now I have some exceptions.

Comment: Actually, my bad. I just noticed that i am not actually working on the entire document.  My code is working on a filtered (by xpath) nodelist.    So, that being the case, I might need to re-evaluate what I am doing entirely.

Comment: Tried it.  Updated the code in my question.  Still isn't working.  I'll work on it more in a few hours.

Comment: @djangofan Now the problem is that you've changed the mode in which you obtain the nodelist. I have exactly you're original code with my change and it's working.

Comment: Ok, I went back to the code you posted above and tried it. It still doesn't work.  I provided a link to some sample XML.  Can you use that and tell me if it works for you?

Comment: Ok, so I initially understood that you want to eliminate every attribute of type: siteKey="siteKey". If you want to eliminate all the attributes siteKey just drop the condition id.equals("siteKey") and remove all the attributes found by the xpath, because all of them are "siteKey".

Comment: Ok, we got it.  Thanks for the help.  I will post my working code as a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code that solved the issue:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;


public class StripAttributes { 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        Document doc = null;
        NodeList nodes = null;
        Set<String> ids = null;
        try {
            doc = factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new File("a.xml"));

            XPathExpression expr = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath()
                    .compile("//@siteKey");
            ids = new HashSet<String>();
            nodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            System.out.println("."); //progress indicator
            Element el = ((Attr) nodes.item(i)).getOwnerElement();
            if ( el.hasAttribute("siteKey") ) el.removeAttribute("siteKey");
        }

        int dupes = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            String id = nodes.item(i).getNodeValue();
            if (ids.contains(id)) {
                System.out.format("%s is duplicate\n\n", id);
                dupes++;
            } else {
                ids.add(id);
            }
        }

        System.out.format("Total ids = %d\n Total Duplicates = %d\n", ids
                .size(), dupes);

        Transformer transformer;
        StreamResult result = null;
        try {
            transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            transformer.transform(source, result);
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerFactoryConfigurationError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String xmlString = result.getWriter().toString();
        System.out.println(xmlString);

    } 
}
```

Also, here is a link to a Groovy translation of this code:

https://gist.github.com/2789163

Answer (score 0):

```
NamedNodeMap attributes = node.getAttributes();
attributes.removeNamedItem(attName);
```