# How to find out if XML element is self-closing?

Tags: java, xml, sax, saxparser

I have googled, searched and read, but have been unable to find an answer.

I have XML-files that look somewhat like this:

```
<Patient PID="5" Disease="Flu" FavoriteBird="Norwegian Blue"/>
<Patient PID="33" Disease="Thripshaw's Disease" FavoriteBird="Dodo">
    <Contact Hospitalized="2013 05 30"/>
</Patient>
```

I want to anonymise each patients' favorite bird. That is, produce output that looks like this:

```
<Patient PID="5" Disease="Flu"/>
<Patient PID="33" Disease="Thripshaw's Disease">
    <Contact Hospitalized="2013 05 30"/>
</Patient>
```

It is all going swimmingly, except for the fact that I can only handle the last type of patient tag- that is, when the element is not self-closing.

My "endElement"-method simply looks like

```
out.write(qName + "/n>")
```

and is never invoked for the first type of Patient tag.

What do I do? If there was a way to find out whether a tag is self-closing or not I could easily fix it.

PS: I have to transform files that are up to several hundred megabytes in size. Please keep that in mind when suggesting alternative solutions.

Comment: are you manually writing out the XML?  that's a big no-no.  you should be using the javax.xml.transform API instead.

Comment: It's not much of an answer to your question, but I'd strongly recommend using a framework such as jdom to handle this sort of thing. It takes a lot of the pain out of it.

Comment: Post the code you use for reading/writing the xml, so we can help.

Comment: I tried writing a simple example because my code for it all is massive. I should probably have used a different method from the very beginning. Sorry.

Comment: But if anyone knows a simple answer to the original question I think it still might be interesting to others so I'll keep the question for now.

Comment: this might help u..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743824/using-java-to-remove-all-xml-attributes-from-a-xml-file-that-match-a-attribute-n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in about five lines of XSLT, rather than the undoubtedly many more lines of SAX handling you have now, and it will work correctly for any legal XML.

Comment: Yeah, I've read up on it. Keeping this question as a warning.